# Understanding something in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

If I use a delimiter on a string:

```
Scanner scanString = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("<.*>");
```

I want to know why this won't preserve the text in

```
<a href="https://post.craigslist.org/c/snj?lang=en">post to classifieds</a>
```

but it will in a line with only

```
<option value="ccc">community
```

While

```
Scanner scanString = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("<.*?>");
```

will work for both.

As I understand it this `"<.*>"` should exclude a string starting with "<" followed by any character 0 or more times until it reaches a ">".  So shouldn't it not start excluding again until it reaches another "<"?

Comment: use a tool like Expresso: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: You may also wish to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the second expression uses a *reluctant* (as opposed to *greedy*) quantifier, which means that it does not attempt to match the entire string and back off from there, like the first one does.

This expression `"<.*>"` tries to advance as far as possible into your input string, so it goes all the way to the end. Once it's there, it discovers that it has a match, and so it stops. The reluctant version `"<.*?>"` does not do that: it matches to the first `>`, and stops.

[This article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) provides a great read on quantifiers.

Comment: Wow that made just made so much sense.  And that article looks extremely helpful.  Thank you!